# Glue how to delete a record on a dataframe using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have doubts how to do in pyspark the deletion of records in a dataframe taking data from another dataframe
as below.
pyspark:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn ("dt_dia", current_date ())
df1 = df1.withColumn ("dt_dia_menos_14_dias", sf.date_add (current_date (), - 14))
df1 = newdf.where (newdf.dt_create> newdf.dt_dia_menos_14_dias | newdf.dt_change> newdf.dt_dia_menos_14_dias)

df2 = df1.withColumn ("dt_dia", current_date ())
df2 = df1.withColumn ("dt_dia_menos_14_dias", sf.date_add (current_date (), - 14))
df2 = newdf.where (newdf.dt_create <= newdf.dt_dia_menos_14_dias | newdf.dt_change <0 newdf.dt_dia_menos_14_dias)
## wanted to include a line here to remove the records I found in df1 where df2 would be without the same records
from df1 the delete would be searching for the fields bank and account and doc. The rule is as follows where the date of inclusion or change equal to 2020-12-21 will be the most updated and the previous one should be replaced


The next step would be to make the union two dataframes

dfResultUNion = df1.union (df2)
```

Can someone help me !

```
df1
===
id; dt_create; dt_change; bank; account; doc; name
1; 2020-12-01 ;; 001; 001; 001; Michael
2; 2020-12-02 ;; 001; 002; 002; Ismael
3; 2020-12-02 ;; 002; 002; 003; Ben

df2
===
id; dt_create; dt_change; bank; account; doc; name
1; 2020-12-01; 2020-12-21; 001; 001; 001; Michael Jachason
2; 2020-12-02 ;; 001; 002; 002; Ismael
9; 2020-12-21 ;; 002; 002; 003; Mary

Result of UNION of df1 and df2

id; dt_create; dt_change; bank; account; doc; name
1; 2020-12-01; 2020-12-21; 001; 001; 001; Michael Jachason
2; 2020-12-02 ;; 001; 002; 002; Ismael
3; 2020-12-02 ;; 002; 002; 003; Ben
9; 2020-12-21 ;; 002; 002; 003; Mary
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `coalesce`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df1.join(
    df2.withColumnRenamed('dt_change', 'dt_change2'),
    df1.columns[:2] + df1.columns[3:],
    'full'
).withColumn(
    'dt_change',
    F.coalesce('dt_change', 'dt_change2')
).select(df1.columns).orderBy('id')

result.show()
+---+----------+----------+----+-------+---+-------+
| id| dt_create| dt_change|bank|account|doc|   name|
+---+----------+----------+----+-------+---+-------+
|  1|2020-12-01|2020-12-21| 001|    001|001|Michael|
|  2|2020-12-02|      null| 001|    002|002| Ismael|
|  3|2020-12-02|      null| 002|    002|003|    Ben|
|  9|2020-12-21|      null| 002|    002|003|   Mary|
+---+----------+----------+----+-------+---+-------+
```

Comment: @Paulo I can't see your message. Please edit the question to put the error message there instead.

Comment: I have the message below after implementing:  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df2' referenced before assignment                                                                                After:  import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df1.join(
    df2.withColumnRenamed('dt_change', 'dt_change2'),
    df1.columns[:2] + df1.columns[3:],
    'full'
).withColumn(
    'dt_change',
    F.coalesce('dt_change', 'dt_change2')
).select(df1.columns).orderBy('id')

Comment: @Paulo that means `df2` is not defined. please check your code to make sure it's defined before my code.

Comment: Mr. mck ,I created another subject with the title Pyspark error: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment if you can help me I would appreciate it

Comment: @Paulo I don't see any new questions. Could you provide a link to your new question?

Comment: title:Pyspark error: UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment  Your question is ready to publish!
Our automated system checked for ways to improve your question and found none.  link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481800/pyspark-error-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment